# Typescript - shows the underlines parameters - what is the issue here

Tags: typescript

I am trying a class approach with `typescript`. it works for me. but i am getting underlined in the construction of 'Song' any one explain me the issue what is here?

Instead of just getting my code corrected, i am looking for the correct understanding here.

here is my code :

```
class Song {

artist:string, title:string - both underlined
    constructor( artist:string, title:string ) {}

    play() {
        console.log( 'Playing' + this.title + ' by' + this.artist );
    }

}

var songs = [

    new Song('Bushbaby', 'Megaphone'),
    new Song('Delays', 'One More Lie In'),
    new Song('Goober Gun', 'Stereo'),
    new Song('Sohnee', 'Shatter'),
    new Song('Get Amped', 'Celebrity')

];

class Jukebox {

    constructor(private songs: Song[]) { };

    run () {

        var song = this.getRandomSong();
        song.play();
    };

    private getRandomSong () {

        var songCount = this.songs.length;
        var songIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * songCount);

        return this.songs[songIndex];

    };
}



var jukebox = new Jukebox(songs);
jukebox.run();
```

[Live](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Song%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%20artist%3Astring%2C%20title%3Astring%20)%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20play()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%20'Playing'%20%2B%20this.title%20%2B%20'%20by'%20%2B%20this.artist%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20songs%20%3D%20%5B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Bushbaby'%2C%20'Megaphone')%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Delays'%2C%20'One%20More%20Lie%20In')%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Goober%20Gun'%2C%20'Stereo')%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Sohnee'%2C%20'Shatter')%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Get%20Amped'%2C%20'Celebrity')%0A%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Jukebox%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20songs%3A%20Song%5B%5D)%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20run%20()%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20song%20%3D%20this.getRandomSong()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20song.play()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20getRandomSong%20()%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20songCount%20%3D%20this.songs.length%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20songIndex%20%3D%20Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20songCount)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.songs%5BsongIndex%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Avar%20jukebox%20%3D%20new%20Jukebox(songs)%3B%0Ajukebox.run()%3B%20)

Answer (score 0):

Just use some semicolons and I think you're good.

```
artist:string;
title:string;
```

[Updated Live](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20Song%20%7B%0A%0Aartist%3Astring%3B%0Atitle%3Astring%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(%20artist%3Astring%2C%20title%3Astring%20)%20%7B%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20play()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%20'Playing'%20%2B%20this.title%20%2B%20'%20by'%20%2B%20this.artist%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20songs%20%3D%20%5B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Bushbaby'%2C%20'Megaphone')%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Delays'%2C%20'One%20More%20Lie%20In')%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Goober%20Gun'%2C%20'Stereo')%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Sohnee'%2C%20'Shatter')%2C%0A%20%20%20%20new%20Song('Get%20Amped'%2C%20'Celebrity')%0A%0A%5D%3B%0A%0Aclass%20Jukebox%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(private%20songs%3A%20Song%5B%5D)%20%7B%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20run%20()%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20song%20%3D%20this.getRandomSong()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20song.play()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20private%20getRandomSong%20()%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20songCount%20%3D%20this.songs.length%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20songIndex%20%3D%20Math.floor(Math.random()%20*%20songCount)%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.songs%5BsongIndex%5D%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Avar%20jukebox%20%3D%20new%20Jukebox(songs)%3B%0Ajukebox.run()%3B%20)

Comment: @user2024080 Done, added link to my answer